# Android - Testing purchasing without a physical phone

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I do not have an Android phone and have hit a snag.

Google says you cannot test In App Purchases on an Emulator, details found [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing).

> Install your application on an Android-powered device. You cannot use
>   an emulator to test Google Play Billing.

**Question 1:** Is this also true for the Genymotion emulator?

If this is truly the case, I guess I could not have in app purchases, and instead have two versions of the product. A Free, limited edition and a paid-for edition.

**Question 2:** If I have a solely paid-for version, do I need anything in my code that needs to be checked? By this, I mean the user can only install a paid-for version once they have paid Google Play. The actual program itself is oblivious that it has been paid for. Do I need anything in my code to indicate it is a paid-for version?

If the Android version sold, I would obviously get a physical machine. But at the moment, I do not want to keep on buying loads of different hardware just to keep on checking stuff.

Comment: piece of advice: *loads of different hardware* - we are talking about just 1 device here. It can by a cheap ass 20$ android 4 if you wish. I would not change the app concept just to avoid needing a device to test on. The emulator is limited in more ways that might hinder you later.

Comment: there are many reasons why you can not test on emulators. thats not the point of this, however, @TimCastelijns is right. All you need is a cheap android device to test. Newer the better in my opinion. Less than 100 bucks, even if u get yourself a prepaid phone and never use it... Do not make two apps. you wont like the outcome of that.

Comment: @DroiDev - what are the outcomes of a **Free** version and a **Full** version?

Comment: @Tim unfortunately the country where I live, the cheapest Android phone is about $100.

Comment: order it online

Comment: @Rewind as a marketing standpoint.... that alone is not a good idea. why? two apps. if i have your free app, i will not download another app. i will also not pay to have another app on my phone. i would much rather buy something in app to do it.

Comment: I know nothing about phones. All I want is no monthly fee, something that can hook into my wireless at home, and something cheap. The cheaper the better. Argos UK http://www.argos.co.uk/ or amazon uk www.amazon.co.uk

Comment: So, you have an iPhone and no money for an Android?

Comment: I do not have any phone. A total waste of money. Laptops do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buying a phone is a personal decision, and you aren't going to get good advice on a programming site. You might be better to try https://android.stackexchange.com/, but even there, opinion based questions "what phone should I get" aren't encouraged as the stackoverflow / stackexchange sites are for things with right and wrong answers, not opinion. If I were you, I'd either do the research myself (if your time isn't valuable). If your time is valuable, I'd just go to argos and get the cheapest Android based phone you can which currently is £15 at Argos right now. (less cost than your time). There'll be something you don't like about it, probably many things, but at that point you'll know what they are and can make a more informed decision.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I cannot see the £15 one you are on about. Do all Android phones do the things I require? (See the edit in my main post.)

Comment: Any android phone which has Google Play will do the things you require. (all have WiFi, I personally would get one with a newish version of Android (O, 8.0 or greater). However this is £15 and has Lollipop (5.1) http://www.argos.co.uk/product/5654640. It will be a terrible phone, but have Android and Google Play and so let you test. It might include a SIM, but you don't have to use it.